# Option Strict on by default in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, option-strict

Whenever I created a new VB.NET program I must go into the project's properties and set 'Option strict' on. Can I do that once so it is a default for every time I create a new project?

Comment: This should be the default behaviour when creating a new project. I have created a UserVoice entry for this: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/10672947-set-option-strict-on-by-default-instead-of-off

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Visual Studio, go menu *Tools* -> *Options* -> *Projects and Solutions* -> VB defaults -> *Option Strict*.  Set it to "On".

Every time you create a new project, it will have *Option Strict On* by default.

Answer (score 5):

Check out *Option Strict* under menu *Tools* -> *Options* -> *Projects and Solutions* -> *VB Defaults*:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your Visual Studio, go to Tools > Options, open Projects and Solutions, and select VB Defaults.

Answer (score 0):

You can set that in the Visual Studio options, under *Projects and Solutions* and *VB Defaults*.