# C# to VB - TrimStart Behavior

Tags: c#, vb.net, string, trim

I have the simplest VB code:

```
Dim test As String = "DDN8057"
Console.WriteLine(test.TrimStart("DDN"))
```

gives me

> N8057

Why?  Converting this to C# (which I'm far more familiar with), made me realize that `TrimStart` actually expects a `params char[]`, but running

```
Console.WriteLine("DDN8057".TrimStart("DDN".ToCharArray()));
```

gives me my expected

> 8057

So, I guess VB is capable of treating a string as a char array internally (is this true?), but why the discrepancy in my output?

Comment: Using either `{"D"c, "D"c, "N"c}` or `"DDN".ToCharArray` in VB gives your expected output. Passing a string when it expects a char array won't work as intended. It simply takes the first letter of the string and ignores the rest. Replace the second D with any other character to check this out

Comment: If you switch Option Strict On (and you should always have it on) - then `test.TrimStart("DDN")` will not compile - for the reason you explained

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have Option Strict switched On in your VB project.

I can tell because `test.TrimStart("DDN")` does not compile when this is on. This is because as you correctly pointed out `TrimStart` expects an explicit *char array* (or a single *char*)

What happens when you run this with Option Strict Off is the compiler coerces the `String` (`DDN`) into a *single* char (`D`) (this is an implicit narrowing conversion which Option Strict expressly forbids) which is why you get `N8057` as your output.

You would think that as a string is just a char array it would convert it to an array but it doesn't - it effectively performs `CChar("DDN")`!

**Conclusion**

Option Strict On = Good. Here is how to switch it on by default: [Option Strict on by default in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160669/option-strict-on-by-default-in-vb-net)

Comment: bah. I forgot about `option strict`.  Even with it off though, it seems radical that VB lets that fly at runtime.

Comment: I thought `option strict off` was like using dynamic in C#.  But based on the `option strict` docs, i guess string to char is a *narrowing conversion*

Comment: @Jonesopolis - there are subtle but important differences between dynamic and Option Strict. The error produced when Strict is On is `BC30512` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4we5x2t7.aspx