# How to split on a string instead of a character?

Tags: vb.net, split

I have a file name like below:

```
sub_fa__hotchkis_type1a__180310__PUO4x4__180813
```

I want to separate it with double underscores "__" and using this code:

```
        Dim MdlNameArr() As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(strProjMdlName).Split(New Char() {"__"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        myTool.Label9.Text = MdlNameArr(1).ToString
```

I expect the result will be "hotchkis_type1a" but it returns "fa".

It doesnt recognize single underscore "_".

Is there any method to use it properly?

Comment: You need to use the [String.Split(string(), options)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Split_System_String___System_StringSplitOptions_) overload.

Comment: If you use [`Option Strict On`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5160669/1115360) it will point out problems like that for you.

Comment: @AndrewMorton can you show us how? I read the documentation a couple of times and i searched on google but i didn't find how the options could help

Comment: @AndrewMorton you deserve an upvote but I used all my votes today :c

Comment: I will tomorrow ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split on a string rather than just a character, so if we look at the available overloads for String.Split, we find the nearest one to that is [String.Split(string(), options)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Split_System_String___System_StringSplitOptions_) which takes an array of strings as the separators and requires the inclusion of [StringSplitOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringsplitoptions?view=netframework-4.7.2) like this:

```
Dim s = "sub_fa__hotchkis_type1a__180310__PUO4x4__180813"
Dim separators() As String = {"__"}
Dim parts = s.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.None)

If parts.Length >= 2 Then
    Console.WriteLine(parts(1))
Else
    Console.WriteLine("Not enough parts found.")
End If
```

Outputs:

> hotchkis_type1a