# VB.NET Operator '&' is not defined for string and type 'Internalfield'

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, adodb, arcobjects

**Background**

Currently working on a plugin in ArcMap done in VBA from early 2000 and refactoring it to VB.NET. The database is a MS Access Database.

Pretty new to VB.NET and coding in general.

**Error**

The issue I'm facing is that I'm getting the error:

> InvalidCastException was unhandled.
>
> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
>
> Additional information: Operator '&' is not defined for string "UPDATE CustomerArea SET Area_m2=547," and type 'InternalField'.

**Code**

```
Dim nr
Dim area_polygon_excl_faktor As Double
Dim area_db

Do While Not AdoRS.BOF
   nr = AdoRS("nr")
   area_db = CDbl(AdoRS("area_m2").Value)

   Dim result As MsgBoxResult
   result = MsgBox(aAttrID(index) & "  " & area_db & "  " & area_polygon_exkl_faktor & "  Would you like to update the area?", vbYesNoCancel, "Update of area")

   If result = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
      strSqlUpdateArea = "UPDATE CustomerArea SET Area_m2='" & area_polygon_excl_faktor & "' WHERE Nr= '" & nr

      AdoConn.Execute(strSqlUpdateArea)

   ElseIf result = MsgBoxResult.No Then

      MsgBox("You have decided not to update the area")

   End If
```

The AdoRS is an ADODB.Recordset. The issue I am facing is on the line:

```
strSqlUpdateArea = "UPDATE CustomerArea SET Area_m2='" & area_polygon_excl_faktor & "' WHERE Nr= '" & nr
```

I've tried rewriting it several times and even adding a Convert.toString in the line *nr = AdoRS("nr"),* but with no luck. I know that the Nr in Access is an AutoNumber (LongInteger).

Comment: In .NET the string concatenator is +, not &.

Comment: @Gustav in VB.Net both & and + can be used for string concatenation, but + performs arithmetic addition when possible.

Comment: Can you set Option Explicit and Strict to On and see what errors you get? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160669/option-strict-on-by-default-in-vb-net. You can also try `nr.Value` instead of just `nr`

Comment: @Slai Thanks for trying to help, but it still gave me the same error.

Comment: @Slai Actually I didn't see the part you wrote nr.Value, which I tried afterwards and it passed the line. Now I got a COMException was unhandled on the line

AdoConn.Execute(strSqlUpdateArea)

Comment: is the SQL query the same as in VBA? It seems like `nr.Value & "'"` is missing at the end

Comment: Tried it out and the line AdoConn.Execute(strSqlUpdateArea) gave me COMException was unhandled. Additional information: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

The old VBA code looked like this:

strSqlUpdateArea = "UPDATE CustomerArea SET Area_m2=" & CDec(area_polygon_excl_faktor) & " WHERE Nr=" & CStr(nr)

Comment: @Anna3anana - Since you are upgrading to VB.NET you might want to consider **(1)** Using .NET's `System.Data.Odbc` (or perhaps `System.Data.OleDb`) instead of the old COM reference to ADODB, and **(2)** Using proper parameterized queries (via `OdbcCommand` or `OleDbCommand`) instead of dynamic SQL (i.e., imbedding values into the SQL command text) so you won't have to deal with "Little Bobby Tables".

Comment: Thanks @GordThompson I did start off with OledDb, but this one feature has 1300 lines of codes and I thought if I would change it would require much more time. I will do a bit more research on changing it and then reconsider! Thanks for the comment!

Comment: @Anna3anana - Fair enough. Even if you stick with ADODB you can still use proper parameterized queries via an `ADODB.Command` object.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was that I had to convert the type InternalField into a string properly and do the steps in the right order.

```
Dim sNr As String
Dim area_polygon_excl_faktor As Double
Dim area_db

Do While Not AdoRS.BOF
   sNr = Convert.ToString(AdoRS("nr").Value)
   area_db = CDbl(AdoRS("area_m2").Value)

   Dim result As MsgBoxResult
   result = MsgBox(aAttrID(index) & "  " & area_db & "  " & area_polygon_excl_faktor & "  Would you like to update the area?", vbYesNoCancel, "Update of area")

   If result = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
      strSqlUpdateArea = "UPDATE CustomerArea Set Area_m2='" & area_polygon_excl_faktor & "' WHERE Nr=" & sNr

   AdoConn.Execute(strSqlUpdateArea)
   ElseIf result = MsgBoxResult.No Then
      MsgBox("You have decided not to update the area")
   End If
```

Answer (score 0):

> The old VBA code looked like this ...

Then no quotes, and force a decimal separator to a dot:

```
Dim format As System.Globalization.CultureInfo

format = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

strSqlUpdateArea = "UPDATE CustomerArea SET Area_m2 = " & area_polygon_excl_faktor.ToString(format) & " WHERE Nr = " & nr.ToString(format)
```